# How to apply a different Master Page for ONLY ONE Controller then all others (MVC 2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages

I am overriding the Master inside OnActionExecuted in BaseController which would apply appropriate Master for all Controller Actions. Pls. see the code below:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) 
{ 
    var action = filterContext.Result as ViewResult; 
    if (action != null) 
    {
        int _tenantID = _configurationManager.GetTenantID(Request.Url.Host);
        var MasterName = GetMasterForTenant(tenantID);
        action.MasterName = MasterName;
    } 
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext); 
}
```

Now I have a requirement to apply a different MASTER ONLY for ONE Controller then all others. How Can I achieve this? **I am using ASP.NET MVC 2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add code to detect whether `this` object's type is your special controller type and apply the different master page.